# Fill up a list using an existing vector and a double for loop

Tags: r, list, loops

I would like to have a list where each item is "Born in " each of the cities of the cities vector.

```
cities <- c("Lausanne", "Zurich", "Geneva")

mylist <- list()

for (i in 1:length(cities)){
  for (city in cities){
    born <- paste0("Born in ", city)
    mylist[[i]] <- born
  }
}
```

I need it in the list format because I have much more complex data and would actually be adding dataframes into the list. I would like to understand how the double loop would work (one for items and one for length).

Thank you!

Comment: `paste0("Born in ", cities)` ?

Comment: I need to put it in a list because I have more complex data and I would like to understand how the loop would work

Comment: `for (i in 1:length(cities)){mylist[[i]] <- paste0("Born in ", cities[i])}`

Comment: or: `mylist <- as.list(paste0("Born in ", cities))`

Comment: Why not just `as.list(paste0('Born in ', cities))`?

Comment: I guess you just need one `for` loop, otherwise you would create a list of duplicates

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the data in list you can use `as.list`

```
as.list(paste0("Born in ", cities))

#[[1]]
#[1] "Born in Lausanne"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Born in Zurich"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Born in Geneva"
```

---

If you really want to use `for` loop, you'll need only one loop

```
mylist <- vector("list", length(cities))
for (i in seq_along(cities)) {
    mylist[[i]] <- paste0("Born in ", cities[i])
}
```